# У меня есть VPS на Ubuntu как получить доступ к файлу?

Tags: ubuntu, vps

У меня есть VPS (Ubuntu) заказал на reg.ru, там в основной директории лежит файл video.mp4, но если в браузере зайду вот так: `http://Ip-адрес-сервера/video.mp4` это не работает, нашел инструкции что надо бы подключить домен по хорошему, но неужели я не могу глянуть видос без домена и без входа в пользователя?

В доках, написано это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132602/discussion-on-question-by-artemgh----vps--ubuntu---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался как это сделать, в итоге налажал просто из-за фигни, в конфиге apache стояла не корневая папка по дефолту, а другая

P.S если всё же ответить на свой вопрос, то: Ставим Apache, и размещаем видео в **корневой** директории